# SQLAlchemy: dynamically apply filter on relationship column ahead of time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, django-rest-framework

I have two SQLAlchemy classes representing a many-to-one relationship, say:

```
class Person
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))
    known_addresses = relationship('Address', backref='person')

class Address:
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id, ondelete='cascade'))
    city = Column(String(30))
    zip_code = Column(String(10))
```

Now, say I have a function that returns a Person queryset (a Select object) filtered by zip codes:

```
def get_persons_in_zip_code(zip_code):
    return session.query(Person).\
        join(Address).\
        where(Address.zip_code == zip_code)
```

Once I return the query set, I have no control over it and it is expected that this will encapsulate all the data that the framework I'm using (in my case Django/DRF) to render a list of persons **along with their addresses** (so the code iterates the query set, calling `.addresses` for each person and rendering that as well).

Here's the catch: I want to ensure that calling `.addresses` will return *only* the addresses matched in the original, `zip_code` filtered query - not all addresses related to that person.

Is there a way to achieve this in SQLAlchemy *without accessing Person objects returned at later stages?* That is, I can only modify my `get_persons_in_zip_code` function, or the original SQLAlchemy classes, but have no access to the Person objects returned from the query, as that happens deep inside the framework rendering code.

**EDIT**: It's also important that calling `count()` on the returned query object yields the number of expected `Person` objects, not the number of `Address` objects.

Comment: do you need to keep returning `Person` objects or would you also be fine with returning some kind of serialised version of a `Person`?

Comment: My code needs to return a`Query` object - I'm not the one returning `Person` objects or otherwise - but a later called part of the framework. I think that as long as that part of the code gets something that matches the `Person` duck-type, it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result).

**EDIT**: An updated version that monkeypatches the `.count()` function to return only the distinct `Person` count.

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, distinct
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, contains_eager
from types import MethodType

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(30))
    known_addresses = relationship('Address', backref='person')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Person {}>".format(self.name)


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id, ondelete='cascade'))
    city = Column(String(30))
    zip_code = Column(String(10))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Address {}>".format(self.zip_code)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

p1 = Person(name="P1")
session.add(p1)
p2 = Person(name="P2")
session.add(p2)

session.commit()

a1 = Address(person_id=p1.id, zip_code="123")
session.add(a1)
a2 = Address(person_id=p1.id, zip_code="345")
session.add(a2)
a3 = Address(person_id=p2.id, zip_code="123")
session.add(a3)
a4 = Address(person_id=p1.id, zip_code="123")
session.add(a4)

session.commit()

def get_persons_in_zip_code(zip_code):
    return session.query(Person).\
        join(Person.known_addresses).\
        filter(Address.zip_code == zip_code).\
        options(contains_eager(Person.known_addresses))

def distinct_person_count(q):
    count_q = q.statement.with_only_columns([func.count(distinct(Person.id))])
    return q.session.execute(count_q).scalar()


results = get_persons_in_zip_code("123")
results.count = MethodType(distinct_person_count, results)

print(results.count())


for person in results:
    print(person)
    for address in person.known_addresses:
        print(address)
```

Output:

```
2
<Person P1>
<Address 123>
<Address 123>
<Person P2>
<Address 123>
```

Comment: This works well, but it has the side effect of `.count()` returning the count of all `Address` objects and not all distinct `Person` objects due to the join. Since I forgot to specify `count()` as a requirement in my original question, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @shevron are you sure? Where are you calling `.count()`? On the result of `get_persons_in_zip_code`? That seems to return the correct value for me (2 in the example above).

Comment: Yes. I think it will fail once a person has two addresses with "123" zip code.

Comment: I added a version that overrides the `.count()` to return the distinct `Person`s only. It's not pretty and there is probably a better way to do this...

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a bit more time and if no other suggestions comes up I'll accept your answer.

Comment: sounds good. I'd also be curious if there is a better solution 